# 'use of undefined type' error when using circular inclusion

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, circular-dependency, forward-declaration

I wrote two classes with these dependencies.

```
//a.h
class B: 
class A{
 B *b ;
 A() { b = new B(this);}
 print();
}



  // b.h
    class A;
    class B{
     A* a;
     B(A *_a){ this->a = _a }
     void foo() { a->print(); } // here i have error : use of undefined type a
   }
```

If I comment 'a->print()' the code compiles and the other function works, but when I use the pointer of class A in class B, I'm getting this error:

> "use of undefined type a"

Can anyone solve my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the implementation of the methods outside the header and inside implementation files.

To do `a->print();` or `new B(this)`, a full definition is required.